# OOP: Coupling the setting of a state with the showing of it?

Tags: objective-c, oop, coding-style

Say I have an class which has three states: full screen, windowed, and minimized. The state of my object is stored as an enumerated type,

```
typedef enum {
    StateFullScreen,
    StateWindowed,
    StateMinimized
} State;
```

If every time I change the `State`, I am calling two methods: `setState:` and `showState:`, should I couple these actions into one? For example, override the normal synthesized `setState:` method and have it depending on the state call the proper `showState:` method? Or should I do it the other way around having `showState:` call `setState:`?

Are either of these good programming practice when it comes to object-oriented design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it would be better to do all the work in setState, this is what someone using your class would expect.

I have a session class, which has statusses connecting, disconnecting, online and offline. If I call setStatus it will also call a delegate method and disconnect the session if the new status is equalto disconnecting or offline.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered creating a ChangeState(...) method?
It would be simple enough to create a first pass refactoring that calls the other two methods.  I'd then work through further refactorings to clean it up fully.

Comment: I voted you up, but I don't think I will go this route as seeing how I don't want either of the methods to be called without the other.

Comment: Then make them private, and call from ChangeState().